# How to convert array(densevectors) into array?

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, numpy-ndarray

In the code below I am trying to implement weighted voting classifier using `EnsembleVoteClassifier()`.

```
from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleVoteClassifier

import copy

eclf = EnsembleVoteClassifier(clfs=[s1, s2], weights=[1,1],refit=False)
```

where s1 and s2 are PySpark pipeline models. Input is images dataset. S1 is pipeline model of featurizer and LogisticRegression. S2 is pipeline model of featurizer and NaiveBayes classifier.

To fit the classifier I need the features of images and labels. To get features I used transformer function. And converted to pandas object.

```
qa = featurizer.transform(train)

pandas_df3=qa.toPandas()

y_pred3 = np.array(pandas_df3['features'])

y_true3 = np.array(pandas_df3['label'])

eclf.fit(y_pred3,y_true3)
```

To predict on  the test set using learned voting classifier eclf  I need the features of test images To get features I used transformer function. And converted to pandas object.

```
qa1 = featurizer.transform(df1)

pandas_df4=qa1.toPandas()

y_pred4 = np.array(pandas_df4['features'])


# used predict () for prediction on test set
eclf.predict(y_pred4)
 # here y_pred4 is array([DenseVector([0.0205, 0.0206, 0.1201, 0.9808, 2.3941, 0.1696, 0.2612, 0.2964, 0.3071, 0.0961, 0.2314, 0.0729, 0.0445, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0585, 0.025, 0.3339, 0.2257, 0.0, 0.7522, 0.0, 0.1125, 0.6402, 0.2077, 0.0101, 0.4223, 0.1546, 0.195, 0.5894, 0.3867, 0.0298, 0.0, 0.3882, 0.086, 2.026, 0.3705, 0.1113, 0.452, 0.0056, 0.0, 0.6452, 0.4749, 0.3708, 0.1639,[DenseVector([.......... which is actually features of an image.
# but this gives me error 'PipelineModel' object has no attribute 'predict'
 # so I thought of converting it into array([],[]) form
```

Also, is there any votingclassifier function like `EnsembleVoteclassifier` in PySpark to implement weighted Ensemble classifier?

Answer (score 0):

Which package are you using to obtain `DenseVector`?

Is it Spark ? If yes, according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector.html), `DenseVector` has a `toArray()` method that returns the underlying `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Yes I am using spark. When I use toArray() it is returning me TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column

Comment: Could you update your initial post with a minimal reproductible example so we can help you further ?

Comment: Yes I will update

Comment: Well, if the error is `'PipelineModel' object has no attribute 'predict'`, that means that the `PipelineModel` class does not have a method called `predict()` so you can not call it. This is easily verified looking at the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.PipelineModel.html). Nothing to do with the type of `y_pred4` at this point. You are just not using the good class at the good spot. I don't know the spark package that much so I won't be able to help further.